# Stringbuilder append form from multiple arrays

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting, stringbuilder

I have a `StringBuilder` and I'm trying to append parameters from multiple lists like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var list1 = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" }
var list2 = new List<string>() { "d", "e" }
sb.AppendFormat(" {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} ", list1, list2);
```

I get an exception :

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less
>   than the size of the argument list.

What I did to make it work is create a temporary list

```
var temp = new List<string>();
temp.AddRange(list1);
temp.AddRange(list2);
sb.AppendFormat(" {0}, {1} ,{2}  ,{3}  ,{4} ", new List().Add);
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something as simple as this:

```
var result = string.Join(",", list1.Concat(list2));
```

You can append this to the string builder like this:

```
sb.Append(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var list1 = new List<string>() {"a", "b", "c"};
var list2 = new List<string>() {"d", "e"};
sb.AppendFormat(" {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4} ", list1.Concat(list2).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```